# OpenGL Precompute Vertices/Matrices for Particle System / Optimization

Tags: c++, opengl, optimization, vbo, particle-system

I have a particle system which I want to make as really fast as possible without any effects on the main display function, I basically placed all particles calculations on a separate infinite thread which I keep synchronized with WaitForEvent() (Windows), DataLock flags, etc.

I use glColorPointer, glNormalPointer, glVertexPointer etc to point to the buffered data on the GPU (glGenBuffers, glBufferData) and then glDrawElements to render them.

At the moment I don't have the code so I hope that won't be a problem but I'll try my best to get the infrastructure described:

- Main [Init]

  1. Create a pre-calc queue 30% in size of N particles and do sequential calculations (Thread 1 #2)
- Thread 1

  1. Wait for Calculate Event signal or if pre-calc queue is not full then continue
  2. Loop through N particles and update position / velocity, storing it in pUpdate
  3. If pre-calc queue is not full, add pUpdate to it
- Main [Render]

  1. glActiveTexture(TEXTURE0)
  2. glCol/glNorm/glTex/glVertexPointer
  3. If pre-calc is empty use the most recent pUpdate
  4. OR use one of the pre-calc and delete
  5. Store item in buffer using glBufferSubData()
  6. DrawElements() to draw them
  7. SwapBuffers

The problem is that the Render function uses about 50 pre-calc per second (which speeds up rendering while there are enough left) before 1 could even be added. In short order the pre-calc is empty so everything slows down and the program reverts to Main-Render #3

Any ideas?

Comment: Why aren't you performing the particle calculations on the GPU?

Comment: Alright thats a start! So how I worked it out is that the shader would basically do the Velocity and Positions calculations per vertex, how would I get the updated position back to the Client side so the next time it can be done again?

Comment: There are two ways of doing it on the GPU that I know of. You can either use transform feedback to update the VBO or use a texture to store the positions and render into the texture. Eitehr way you want to avoid copying the position back to the client (cpu) as that is an expensive operation.

Comment: I don't know which OpenGL version you're using, but if it's supported your best option is a compute shader with ssbo. You first update the particles in the ssbo with the compute shader, place a barrier and then draw using the same buffer as input for vertex shader.

Comment: @Luple Thanks so much I'll go and try both methods but honestly transform feedback seems to be my favourite

Comment: @Rhu Mage good point! SSBO may be supported by my machine so I'll check tonight